# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication

Tags: c#

I have an c# application using 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication .NET Programming Interface DLL.
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll)
I need there the TransSubscription and TransPublication.

I can build the solution without any error or warning, and run it in Debug and Release mode on my computer. But if I would like to start the release application an another computer, i receive the error:

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'*

I tried it to have as x64 and x86 application, no affect. I cannot interop the DLL, there will be errors in Vistual studio.

Anyone has an idea?
Thank you

---

Edit:
Meanwhile i did some more testing..
I have installed on a new VM SQL server to get only the available, and in the rght version dll. Installed VS and build the project. This was sucessful, no errors. But if i am starting the app, already in debug mode it crashed with the same error code. any idea?
The dll is referenced all build is completed.

---

Edit:
According: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/concepts/replication-management-objects-concepts?view=sql-server-ver15 i need to add Replication Agent Library (REPLAGNT.dll) but this i cannot do in VS, "A reference to .... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". What do i do wrong?

Comment: The error says, the file is not there. Have you checked, that it is?

Answer (score 0):

For me it sounds like you referenced a dll which is located in a local folder, which works okay as long as you are working on your machine, but crashes as soon as you using another machine. After a build/rebuild a dll should be located in the bin folder.

Comment: Yes, the Microsoft.SqlServer.Rmo.dll it is located in the bin/Release folder after build.

Comment: Okay, what kind of application is it? 
When you publish your application, is the DLL also in the publish folder along with the other DLL's? 

Just three other fix approaches right out of my head:
1. try to delete the bin and obj folders and rebuild the solution
2. delete the reference and add it new

Comment: I would like to start the snapshot agent and push the push-subscription to replicate this to another server. Again, in debug and release mode on my computer it is working. I deleted those folder already and re-created the build, no changes. I did not published the application.

Comment: Meanwhile i did some more testing.. I have installed on a new VM SQL server to get only the available, and in the rght version dll. Installed VS and build the project. This was sucessful, no errors. But if i am starting the app, already in debug mode it crashed with the same error code. any idea? The dll is referenced all build is completed.

Comment: According: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/concepts/replication-management-objects-concepts?view=sql-server-ver15 i need to add Replication Agent Library (REPLAGNT.dll) but this i cannot do in VS, "A reference to .... could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component". What do i do wrong?